# Did my OSX 10.8.2 computer crash or go to sleep due to inactivity?

Tags: macos, java, ide

I left a Java program `AppMain` running on my Retina MBP overnight and in the morning it looked like the program died at around 12:46 am before completing. Since the program works fine when I am actively using the machine, I am wondering whether OS X decided to go to sleep despite 'never-sleep-when-plugged-in' energy saving pref.

By looking at `system.log` excerpt below, could someone please help me figure out whether:

- AppMain (and/or IDEA) shutdown on its own or
- was forced to shutdown by the OS
- if latter, did the machine go to sleep or reboot? why?

> /private/var/log/system.log:

```
Feb 26 00:35:45 NikitaMac mdworker[11751]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:35:45 NikitaMac sandboxd[11752] ([11751]): mdworker(11751) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:35:45 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11752) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 00:39:46 NikitaMac mdworker[11754]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:39:46 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11756) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 00:39:46 NikitaMac sandboxd[11756] ([11754]): mdworker(11754) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:40:31 NikitaMac netbiosd[50]: name servers down?
Feb 26 00:41:47 NikitaMac mdworker[11759]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:41:47 NikitaMac sandboxd[11760] ([11759]): mdworker(11759) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:41:47 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11760) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 00:44:24 NikitaMac kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=11763[GoogleSoftwareUp] clearing CS_VALID
Feb 26 00:45:48 NikitaMac mdworker[11766]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:45:48 NikitaMac sandboxd[11767] ([11766]): mdworker(11766) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:45:48 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11767) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 00:46:48 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: Application App:"AppMain" [ 0x0/0xc06c06]  @ 0x0x7fcda2ebb1a0 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontASNs ( ( ASN:0x0-0xc3cc3c:, ASN:0x0-0x1001:) ), so denying.
Feb 26 00:46:48 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to AppMain, psn 0x0-0xc06c06, securitySessionID=0x186a6, err=-13066
Feb 26 00:46:49 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=100
Feb 26 00:46:49 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyChildDeath to notificationID=4850
Feb 26 00:46:49 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=100
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: Application App:"IntelliJ IDEA" [ 0x0/0x6c06c0]  @ 0x0x7fcda484ab90 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontASNs ( ( ASN:0x0-0xc3cc3c:, ASN:0x0-0x1001:) ), so denying.
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to IntelliJ IDEA, psn 0x0-0x6c06c0, securitySessionID=0x186a6, err=-13066
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.ShareKitHelper[1533]: --warning: [ShareKit-XPC] Received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.ShareKitHelper[1533]: --warning: [ShareKit-XPC] connectionWithClientInterrupted
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.ShareKitHelper[1533]: --warning: [ShareKit] Cancel UI for running services with Client PID: 11520
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[564] ([0x0-0x42042].com.apple.Terminal[732]): Exited: Killed: 9
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: dict count after removing entry for window 0x22 is 0
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac login[11236]: DEAD_PROCESS: 11236 ttys002
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.ShareKitHelper[1533]): Exited: Killed: 9
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[564] ([0x0-0xc07c07].com.apple.Preview[11520]): Exited: Killed: 9
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435459 (ipc/send) invalid destination port from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=150
Feb 26 00:46:50 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[564] (com.apple.talagent[579]): Exited: Killed: 9
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=116
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyLaunchFinished to notificationID=100
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[564] ([0x0-0xd00d].com.apple.iTunesHelper[608]): Exited with code: 1
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[564] ([0x0-0x16016].com.apple.ImageCaptureExtension2[656]): Exited: Killed: 9
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[564] ([0x0-0x17017].com.apple.AppleSpell[661]): Exited: Killed: 9
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [UserAgentDied:139] User Agent @port=43527 Died
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac login[3688]: DEAD_PROCESS: 3688 ttys001
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=7078
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[564] (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua[567]): Exited: Killed: 9
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=100
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: _CGXGetWindowOrderingGroup: Operation on a window 0x15 requiring rights 0x5 by caller Dashboard
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: _CGXGetWindowOrderingGroup: Operation on a window 0x14 requiring rights 0x5 by caller Dashboard
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: _CGXGetWindowOrderingGroup: Operation on a window 0x13 requiring rights 0x5 by caller Dashboard
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: _CGXGetWindowOrderingGroup: Operation on a window 0x12 requiring rights 0x5 by caller Dashboard
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: CGXOrderWindowList: Operation on a window 0x15 requiring rights kCGSWindowRightPresenter by caller Dashboard
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac DashboardClient[1086]: CGSOrderWindowList
Feb 26 00:46:50 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=161
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac loginwindow[55]: DEAD_PROCESS: 55 console
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac loginwindow[55]: Application terminate returned -600
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac airportd[11771]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “escuela3”. Bailing on auto-join.
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435459 (ipc/send) invalid destination port from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=142
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: CGXRestartSessionWorkspace: session workspace exited for session 256 (on console)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: Session 256 released (1 references)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: Session 256 released (0 references)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[80]: loginwindow connection closed; closing server.
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac loginwindow[55]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
Feb 26 00:46:51 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac coreservicesd[27]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435459 (ipc/send) invalid destination port from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyBringForwardRequest to notificationID=101
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac apsd[70]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac loginwindow[11773]: Login Window Application Started
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Server is starting up
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Session 256 released (1 references)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: mux_initialize: Mode is dynamic
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: GLCompositor enabled for tile size [256 x 256]
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: CGXGLInitMipMap: mip map mode is on
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: true
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x04280380: GL mask 0x11; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a00e, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x000006100000a00e0000000004280380
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003f
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003e
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003d
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Created shield window 0x4 for display 0x04280380
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Created shield window 0x5 for display 0x003f003f
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Created shield window 0x6 for display 0x003f003e
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Created shield window 0x7 for display 0x003f003d
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x04280380: GL mask 0x11; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 27 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a00e, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x000006100000a00e0000000004280380
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003f
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003e
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff003f003d
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]:   Display 0x04280380: MappedDisplay Unit 0; Alias(4, 0x11); Vendor 0x610 Model 0xa00e S/N 0 Dimensions 13.03 x 8.15; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1440 x 900], Rotation 0, Resolution 2
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]:   Display 0x003f003f: MappedDisplay Unit 3; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2464,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]:   Display 0x003f003e: MappedDisplay Unit 2; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2465,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]:   Display 0x003f003d: MappedDisplay Unit 1; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2466,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: CGXMuxBoot: Boot normal
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022647, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004843, unit 0, caps QEX|QGL|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022647, GL mask 0x0000000f, texture units 8, texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000010, accelerator 0x00004753, unit 4, caps QEX|QGL|MIPMAP, vram 580 MB
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000010, texture units 8, texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Created shield window 0x8 for display 0x04280380
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x0(0)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x0(0)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac loginwindow[11773]: **DMPROXY** Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: no lock state data
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x04280380: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac airportd[11771]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “escuela3”. Bailing on auto-join.
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac launchctl[11777]: com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac hidd[59]: CGSShutdownServerConnections: Detaching application from window server
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac hidd[59]: CGSDisplayServerShutdown: Detaching display subsystem from window server
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100024 created
Feb 26 00:46:51 NikitaMac loginwindow[11773]: Login Window Started Security Agent
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac SecurityAgent[11784]: MacBuddy was run = 0
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac locationd[11785]: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x8000100 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac locationd[11785]: NOTICE,Location icon should now be in state 0
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac UserEventAgent[11779]: cannot find useragent 1102
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac CVMServer[535]: Check-in to the service com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64 failed. This is likely because you have either unloaded the job or the MachService has the ResetAtClose attribute specified in the launchd.plist. If present, this attribute should be removed.
Feb 26 00:46:52 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac SecurityAgent[11784]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:fraction:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac SecurityAgent[11784]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac SecurityAgent[11784]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 26 00:46:52 NikitaMac SecurityAgent[11784]: *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Feb 26 00:46:53 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 26 00:46:53 NikitaMac WindowServer[11775]: Display 0x04280380: MappedDisplay Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 26 00:47:20 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 26 00:47:20 NikitaMac com.apple.usbmuxd[39]: stopping.
Feb 26 00:47:21 NikitaMac com.apple.usbmuxd[11795]: usbmuxd-296.3 on Jul 25 2012 at 00:28:37, running 64 bit
Feb 26 00:47:23 NikitaMac kernel[0]: (default pager): [KERNEL]: default_pager_backing_store_monitor - send LO_WAT_ALERT
Feb 26 00:47:23 NikitaMac kernel[0]: macx_swapoff SUCCESS
Feb 26 00:47:56 NikitaMac kernel[0]: (default pager): [KERNEL]: default_pager_backing_store_monitor - send LO_WAT_ALERT
Feb 26 00:48:06 NikitaMac kernel[0]: macx_swapoff SUCCESS
Feb 26 00:49:48 NikitaMac mdworker[11798]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:49:48 NikitaMac sandboxd[11799] ([11798]): mdworker(11798) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:49:49 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11799) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 00:51:49 NikitaMac mdworker[11801]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:51:49 NikitaMac sandboxd[11803] ([11801]): mdworker(11801) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:51:50 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11803) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 00:55:50 NikitaMac mdworker[11805]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:55:50 NikitaMac sandboxd[11807] ([11805]): mdworker(11805) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:55:50 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11807) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 00:59:51 NikitaMac mdworker[11810]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 00:59:51 NikitaMac sandboxd[11811] ([11810]): mdworker(11810) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 00:59:51 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11811) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 01:01:51 NikitaMac mdworker[11814]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
Feb 26 01:01:52 NikitaMac sandboxd[11815] ([11814]): mdworker(11814) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ls.boxd
Feb 26 01:01:52 NikitaMac kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(11815) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Feb 26 01:05:52 NikitaMac mdworker[11818]: Unable to talk to lsboxd
```

Comment: are you 'putting hard disks to sleep when possible'?  My MBP with ML did do that even though I explicitly set 'never sleep when plugged in'.  That caused a host of issues.

Comment: It's not clear if that "failed to be brought forward" error is a relevant clue. I might look over `pmset -g log` for the time surrounding that event and just set things up to repeat this test three days running. You'll know in short order if this is a programmatic bug, since machines are low on creativity and should reproduce the same error if it's due to sleep/wake interaction with that one app.